# How to know who created a specific kubernetes object

Tags: go, kubernetes

I'm actually curious to know is there any way to get the user who created a specific object in kubernetes. I am using kubernetes [client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) library.

from my understanding kubernetes object doesn't hold any user-meta information. So how should I approach this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a custom [admission webhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/) which mutates the CRUD request for any object coming to kubernetes API server and add the user as a label to the object.This way you will always know who created the object by looking at that label. Also make sure to use validation admission webhook to reject any edit by the users to that label so that the information can not be changed or tampered.

Answer (score 0):

Auditing describes the who, when and what: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/. I think the way that you use it is to configure a logging backend which stores the logs and then allows you to query what happened.

Comment: thanks! so you are suggesting to configure the logging backend .. like fluentd to the nodes to monitor the Audit logging events? but I'm actually looking for some propertise of a object that will hold the user infromation.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was suggesting, but it wouldn't automatically end up with labels on the object. You'd have to query another API. The other answer would be better for that.